# How does Java quickly compare two collection are exactly the same in Java?

Tags: java, collections, arraylist, hashset

How does Java quickly compare two collection are exactly the same in java?

for example:

if this collection is Set, compare their contain the same object and their size are same.

Code looks like the following

```
public boolean isSameSets(Set<T> set1, Set<T> set2){

    if (set1.size() != set2.size()) {
        return false;
    }

    return set1.containAll(set2) && set2.containAll(set1);
}
```

But if the collection is list, because list is sorted collection, we can iterate to compare every element, I think this way is not the best, who could please tell me how to quickly compare them?

========================================================

Thanks everyone, actually, Collection equals method can do it, include Set and List.

Comment: what is wrong with [Collection::equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#equals(java.lang.Object)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Collection `equals(Object)` method should do this for you.  The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) explains exactly what "equals" means for a Collection, and the semantics are further refined for the interfaces that extend Collection.

Different collection classes will have their own implementations of this method, tuned for their respective semantic models and representations.  So for instance, the `equals` method on a `List` would take account of the element order, but the `equals` method on a `Set` would typically not.

Someone asks:

> cant we use containsAll(Collection).

In general, no.  For instance, two lists that have the same elements are not necessarily equal.  You have to also consider list order.  (And besides, using `containsAll` to compare lists is `O(N^2)` where an efficient `equals` implementation for a `List` should be `O(N)` ... in the worst case.)

The same applies to using `retainsAll`.

Comment: You mean, the `equals` method on a `Set` *cannot* check element order, by definition of a `Set` :)

Comment: @TimPote - you have to be careful with statements like that.  It depends on how closely the implementation class follows the letter / spirit of the `Set` contract.  That's why I stated my Answer the way I did.

Comment: But `equals` doesn't work on two `Collection<>` objects if one of them (for example) is a custom class that `extends AbstractCollection<Integer>`. What then?

Answer (score 4):

The [`HashSet.equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractSet.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method already does comparisons to make sure there are the exact same elements in each set.  The [`ArrayList.equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) does the same except it also checks ordering.

Comment: cant we use containsAll(Collection) ??

Comment: That essentially checks the intersection of the two collections.  You also need to check the size, which `equals` does already.  You also need to check ordering on `List`s.

Comment: ok kool.. i just for a minute thought it would compare both the collections. +1 for you :)

Comment: Thanks, ArrayList.equals can do it, contain sort and size compare.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Collection.retainAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection))

Comment: `Collection.retainAll()`, The `Collections` class is different from the `Collection` class.

Answer (score 0):

Also consider using Google Guava library:

```
elementsEqual(Iterable, Iterable)
```

Returns true if the iterables have the same elements in the same order.
Even if collections are HashSet where the order is not predifined, but the number of elements is the same and the elements are equal, during iterating you'll find out that the order of both sets is the same, provided with correct `hashCode` and `equals` methods.